# Right button on pin annotation not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, titanium-mobile

I have researched everything and still can not figure out how to call the details page for an annotation so the user can then get directions to the pin.

```
mapview.addEventListener('click', function(e){
if (evt.clicksource == 'rightButton' )
{   
    Ti.API.info("Opening detail window");
    navGroup.open(AZdetails.js);
}
```

});

I have seen other code like this but still can not figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not give js file directly to `navGroup`. You have to create a window object and pass it to the `navGroup` like this:

```
mapview.addEventListener('click', function(e){

        if (evt.clicksource == 'rightButton' ) {   
            Ti.API.info("Opening detail window");
            var AZdetails = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
              url:'AZdetails.js'
            });
            navGroup.open(AZdetails); 
        }

});
```

Comment: I fixed my code however when I click the right button on the annotation nothing happens and I now get this message in the console:
message = "Can't find variable: navGroup";

Any advice?

Comment: @rzeno: Have you created navGroup?